# EM algorithm get new parameters by optimizing the Q function (lower bound of likelihood function) or optimizing the likelihood function

Tags: machine-learning, gaussian-mixture-distribution, expectation-maximization, finite-mixture-model

We know that in the EM (Expectation-Maximization) algorithm, the E-step determines the $Q$ function by calculating expectations, which is a lower bound of the likelihood function. In the M-step, by optimizing the $Q$ function, we obtain new parameters $\theta_{new}$, thus increasing the likelihood function $L(X|\theta)$.

Generally, the formula to update parameters in the M-step is obtained by miximize the $Q$ function. However, I've seen some articles that maximize the likelihood function $L$ directly and achieve the same results.

For instance, when using the EM algorithm to solve for the parameters of a GMM (Gaussian Mixture Model), the formula for updating parameters derived from the derivative of the $Q$ function looks the same as the one derived from the derivative of the likelihood function $L(X|\theta)$, as shown below. The $w_l^{(i)}$ represents the posterior probability given $X$ and parameter $\theta$. You can try deriving it, and indeed, the results obtained from optimizing $Q$ and optimizing $L$ have the same form.

[image]

The only difference is that in the results derived from $L(X|\theta)$, the posterior probabilities of the latent variables are unknown. Yet, when maximizing the $Q$ function, we work with known posterior probabilities of the latent variables. Despite these differences, the two forms appear consistent.

This leads to my question:
After obtaining the posterior probabilities of the latent variables $Z$ in the E-step, can we directly maximize the likelihood function $L$, then substitute in the posterior probabilities of the latent variables to solve for the new parameters? Would this approach be equivalent to updating the parameters by maximizing the $Q$ function?